# C# Start Word without com interop with default folder parameter

Tags: c#, .net

We have a C# WPF application which has a button in it which does nothing more than start Word with a working folder parameter so that users, when saving the document, automatically arrive in the right folder.

We have a problem since the last Office update that for SOME users all Word addins are gone when starting Word using this button. When starting Word normally (from outside our application) all AddIns are there (again).

This problem doesn't happen for all users even though the version of our application and the Word version is exactly the same.

**Is there any way to fix this issue OR start Word in any other way (without COM interop) while also passing a working folder parameter or is this fixable with COM interop?**

Thanks very much in advance! :)

I looked at starting Word by using Process.Start(), but then it's not possible to pass a working folder parameter: 
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/command-line-switches-for-microsoft-office-products-079164cd-4ef5-4178-b235-441737deb3a6

Besides that I tried executing a batch command. I saw in this article it's possible to start Word with a working folder parameter, but I can't get that to work.

https://ss64.com/nt/start.html

The button starts Word using a COM interop and the following code:

```
public void StartWord(){
    _officeExport.GetActiveWordApplication();
        if (Directory.Exists(_dossierLocatie.CompleteLocatie))
        {
            succeeded = _officeExport.ChangeWordFileStartupPath(_dossierLocatie.CompleteLocatie);
        }
        if (succeeded)
            _officeExport.TryToActivateWordScreen();
        else
        {
            new DialogService(Presets.Foutmelding).Message("De map van het dossier kan niet gevonden worden.")
                .ShowDialogNow();
        }
}

public Word.Application GetActiveWordApplication()
    {
        if (_activeWordApplication == null)
        {
            SetWordApplication();
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                // Controleer of een actief document nog opgehaald kan worden zo niet dan nieuwe instantie openen.
                // ReSharper disable once UnusedVariable
                var document = _activeWordApplication.ActiveDocument;
            }
            catch
            {
                SetWordApplication();
                return _activeWordApplication;
            }
        }
        return _activeWordApplication;
    }

public bool ChangeWordFileStartupPath(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            _activeWordApplication.Options.set_DefaultFilePath(WdDefaultFilePath.wdDocumentsPath, path);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

public void TryToActivateWordScreen()
    {
        try
        {
            if (_activeWordApplication != null)
            {
                _activeWordApplication.Visible = true;
                _activeWordApplication.Activate();
            }

            if (_activeWordDocument != null)
            {
                _activeWordDocument.Activate();
                foreach (var window in _activeWordDocument.Windows)
                {
                    window.WindowState = WdWindowState.wdWindowStateMinimize;
                    window.WindowState = WdWindowState.wdWindowStateMaximize;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _exceptionLogger.LogException(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try setting the Process Environmental variable.  See : https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Storage-at-Microsoft/Redirecting-Windows-Special-Folders-to-Work-Folders/ba-p/425584

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for the response. I need to be able to pass a different working folder for every time you open Word and every Word instance though.

Comment: So set the environmental variable inside the Process to the correct path.